# Mongoose insertMany - Missing createdAt

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose in my Node micro service application.

I have a model with 'createdAt' that created automatically:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const recordSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    source: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true
    },
    coin: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true
    },
    rate: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    isError: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true
    },
}, { timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at' } });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Record', recordSchema);
```

And I try to insert a bulk of documents into it, like this:

```
// Save the fetched data into the database.
const saveCoinsData = (coinsData) => {
    RecordModel.collection.insertMany(coinsData, (err) => {
        if (err) { logger.error(err); }
    });
};
```

For some reason, if I insert a single document the 'createdAt' is created as expected. But if I use the insertMany function, it's not working and no 'createdAt' (or created_at) is created.

Is this normal?
Is this a bug in mongoose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using mongoose schema here. You're using default node drivers by using [schema].collection.[method]. Referring to [this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany) you can just use
`RecordModel.insertMany` instead, that should add the timestamps.

Comment: Good to know. What is the correct syntax in this case?

Comment: As i said, instead of `RecordModel.collection.insertMany`, try `RecordModel.insertMany`

Comment: Did this work?  I am running into a similar issue except I am using `Notification.insertMany` where `Notification` is the model schema exported as above.  For my case `updatedAt` is being populated but the `createdAt` timestamp is not.  For now I've gotten around it by simply manually adding `createdAt: new Date()` to each of the docs I am using in the `insertMany`

Comment: @SKeney Open a new issue with your code just as above and send me a link, I'll look into it :)

Comment: @JonathanNielsen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72003775/model-insertmany-does-not-create-createdat-or-updatedat-timestamps .  Here is a link.  Sorry this took so long.  Forgot about it.  I've been getting around it thus far by just doing `createdAt: Date.now()` but I'd love to figure out how to have it automatically managed via `timestamps` option in Schema definition.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of insertMany, maybe try create?

create triggers middleware save() which supports timestamps.

Reference:
[Model.create](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create)

Unfortunately I cannot try this now, above is just based on Mongoose documentations